# Calling a constructor vs defining an inline constant as a default parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function that has a configuration struct as an argument

```
struct Config
{
  Config(); //<-- default constructor
  // some configuration constants
};

int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = Config());
```

The definition for `Config()` and the `computeSomethingFrom(...)` are both in the same source file.

My guess is that each function call will be forced to construct `Config` since there's no way to know if the default constructor depends on something else in the environment. This might get expensive if the configuration structure becomes large or the function is called many times.

Still, I'd rather avoid creating another constant if I can. And it's *possible*, given that the default constructor and the function are defined in the same source file, that the compiler can deduce that `Config()` always returns the same thing.

So is there any way to avoid doing something like

```
inline Config DEFAULT_CONFIG = Config();
```

and then declaring the function as

```
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = DEFAULT_CONFIG);
```

?

Comment: I don't get the question.  What's wrong with `int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = Config());`?  If you don't give it an object it will give you the default one.

Comment: I'm worried that calling the default constructor many times might get expensive if this config struct becomes large

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Just overload this function:

```cpp
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config); // note no default value
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg);
```

I do not know how this impacts your code since you didn't give any informatin what `computeSomethingFrom` does.

One of possible implementations (probably you will not be happy with that):

```cpp
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg)
{
    static const Config cfg;
    return computeSomethingFrom(arg, cfg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> So is there any way to avoid doing something like
>
> ```
> inline Config DEFAULT_CONFIG = Config();
> ```
>
> and then declaring the function as
>
> ```
> int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = DEFAULT_CONFIG);
> ```

You can indeed declare global (at file scope) and use that:

```
/*static*/ const Config DEFAULT_CONFIG = Config();
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = DEFAULT_CONFIG);
```

That would call constructor once at "start" (as other global), even if you don't need it.

You might so create a "lazy" factory:

```
const Config& DefaultConfig() {
    static Config config; // Call only once
    return config;
}

int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config = DefaultConfig());
```

It is mainly as other proposals with overloads:

```
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config);
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg)
{
    static const Config config;

    return computeSomethingFrom(arg, config);
}
```

but handles several defaulted parameters for same function,
and handles same default for several functions.

Answer (score 2):

> My guess is that each function call will be forced to construct Config since there's no way to know if the default constructor depends on something else in the environment.

You'd be amazed at what any modern compiler can do.  All empty code will be optimised away. You want to concentrate more readability, rather than trying to out guess the compiler. Only after you've done performance analysis on running code and identified a bottleneck, then try to so some optimisation there.

Comment: IMO, this should be a comment.

Comment: @DanielLangr Totally disagree, I think this is the crux of the matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pollute the global space with a default instance, and you like to avoid creating an object in every function call then I would suggest overloading the function.  Have one version that takes a `Config` and another that doesn't.  Then in the one that doesn't you create a `static Config` so you'll only have one instance constructed.  This will still have a slight cost since static variables need some guarding to make sure they are not initialized more than once.  That would look like

```
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg, const Config& config)
{
    // do the stuff
}
int computeSomethingFrom(Something arg)
{
    static Config config{};
    computeSomethingFrom(std::move(arg), config);
}
```